# How to implementing EasyPay Pakistan Payment gateway in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, payment-gateway

Hi Everyone I am trying to implement the EasyPay Pakistan payment gateway for my website but i am getting this error `Parameter Authentication failed` my code is below which is in plugin they provided:

```
<?php 
require '../../../wp-config.php';

    $storeId = get_option('storeId');
    $daysToExpire = get_option('daysToExpire');
    
    $live = get_option('live');
    $liveVal = $live['menu'];
    $easypayIndexPage = '';
    if ($liveVal == 'no') {
        $easypayIndexPage = 'https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf';
    } else {
        $easypayIndexPage = 'https://easypay.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf';
    }

    $merchantConfirmPage = home_url().'/wp-content/plugins/Easypay/confirmEasypay.php';

    $options = get_option('autoRedirect');
    //$autoRedirect = checked( isset( $options['autoRedirectCb'] ) );
    $autoRedirect = checked( isset( $options['autoRedirectCb'] ),1,false ); 
    if($autoRedirect) {
        $autoRedirect = 1;
    } else {
        $autoRedirect = 0;
    }   
    
    $orderId = $_GET['orderId'];
    if (strpos($_GET['amount'], '.') !== false) {
        $amount = $_GET['amount'];
    } else {
        $amount = sprintf("%0.1f",$_GET['amount']);
    }
    
    $custEmail = $_GET['custEmail'];
    $custCell = $_GET['custCell'];
    $hashKey = get_option('hashKey');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
    $expiryDate = '';
    $currentDate = new DateTime();
    if($daysToExpire != null) {
        $currentDate->modify('+'.$daysToExpire.'day');
        $expiryDate = $currentDate->format('Ymd His');
    }
    
    $paymentMethods = get_option('paymentMethod');
    $paymentMethodVal = $paymentMethods['methods'];
    
    $hashRequest = '';
    if(strlen($hashKey) > 0 && (strlen($hashKey) == 16 || strlen($hashKey) == 24 || strlen($hashKey) == 32 )) {
        // Create Parameter map
        $paramMap = array();
        $paramMap['amount']  = $amount ;
        $paramMap['autoRedirect']  = $autoRedirect ;
        if($custEmail != null && $custEmail != '') {
            $paramMap['emailAddr']  = $custEmail ;
        }
        if($expiryDate != null && $expiryDate != '') {
            $paramMap['expiryDate'] = $expiryDate;
        }
        if($custCell != null && $custCell != '') {
            $paramMap['mobileNum'] = $custCell;
        }
        $paramMap['orderRefNum']  = $orderId ;
        
        if($paymentMethodVal != null && $paymentMethodVal != '') {
            $paramMap['paymentMethod']  = $paymentMethodVal ;
        }       
        $paramMap['postBackURL'] = $merchantConfirmPage;
        $paramMap['storeId']  = $storeId ;
        
        //Creating string to be encoded
        $mapString = '';
        foreach ($paramMap as $key => $val) {
            $mapString .=  $key.'='.$val.'&';
        }
        $mapString  = substr($mapString , 0, -1);
        

        // Encrypting mapString
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-ECB");
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $crypttext = openssl_encrypt($mapString, $cipher, $hashKey,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hashRequest = base64_encode($crypttext);
    
    }
    
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_errno());    
    }     
    mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME);
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'easypay_order';
    
    // mysql inserting an order with pending status
    $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name."( easypay_order_id, easypay_order_info, easypay_order_status, ipn_attr ) VALUES ('$orderId' ,'null',  'pending',  'null')";
    try {
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {            
        error_log($ex->getMessage());
    }
// echo $easypayIndexPage;
 //echo "\r\n".$storeId;
 // echo $amount;
  //echo $merchantConfirmPage;
  //echo $orderId;
 // echo $hashRequest;
 //<?php  header("Location: $easypayIndexPage") ?>


<form name="easypayform" method="post" action="<?php echo $easypayIndexPage;  ?>"> 
    <input name="storeId" value="<?php echo $storeId ?>" hidden = "true" readOnly="true" />
    <input name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount ?>" hidden = "true"/>
    <input name="postBackURL" value="<?php echo $merchantConfirmPage ?>" hidden = "true" readOnly="true" />
    <input name="orderRefNum" value="<?php echo $orderId ?>" hidden = "true" readOnly="true" />
    <?php if ($expiryDate != '' && $expiryDate != null) { ?>
        <input name="expiryDate" value="<?php echo $expiryDate ?>" hidden = "false"/>
    <?php } ?>  
    <input name="autoRedirect" value="<?php echo $autoRedirect ?>" hidden = "true"/>
    <input name="emailAddr" value="<?php echo $custEmail ?>" hidden = "true"/>
    <input name="mobileNum" value="<?php echo $custCell ?>" hidden = "true"/>
    <input name="merchantHashedReq" value="<?php echo $hashRequest ?>" hidden = "true"/>
    <input name="paymentMethod" value="<?php echo $paymentMethodVal ?>" hidden = "true"/>
    
</form>

<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
   document.easypayform.submit();
</script>
```

When I click on `Proceed to easypay` nothing appears on the page and just white black page appears, so after research I came to know that this below written code is not working:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
   document.easypayform.submit();
</script>
```

Therefore I added this line of code into my form so that I can manually click the button so redirect to EasyPay page.

```
<input type = "submit" value="Submit">
```

Now, when clicking on the submit button it is redirecting to EasyPay page but this error occurs saying `Parameter Authentication failed`.

[image]

So, is there anyone who can help me out in this implementation because there support team is not helpful.
I will be very thankful for your help.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue ? I'm also facing the same problem

Comment: no luck till now

Comment: @casper123 changing Number of decimals to 1 in currency setting will resolve this issue

Comment: I already tried but it still doesn't work. I'm using codeigniter php

Comment: updating my code with your hash generation made it worked :) thanks :)

Comment: but now on confirmation page I get the error "This request is already in process."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This EasyPay plugin can't accept payment values greater than 2 decimals, so, by going in Woo-Commerce plugin in the currency's setting and changing number of decimals to 1 the EasyPay plugin issue will be resolve.